# "Either or" validation of multiple inputs with same error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

My form has four fields. I need:
  - validation to succeed if at least one field is populated
  - to use the same error for all the fields "Please enter a phone or email"

The code below does not work on a contigent basis- all fields are validated separately even though I use the function to check them all at once. What am I doing wrong?

```
var rule = function (el) {
//return                                        <-- old
  return (                                    //<-- new
    ($("#CustomerEmail").val() === "") &&
    ($("#CustomerMobile").val() === "") &&
    ($("#CustomerWork").val() === "") &&
    ($("#CustomerHome").val() === "")
  //;                                         <-- old
    );                                      //<-- new
  };

$("#CustomerEmail").rules("add", { required: rule });
$("#CustomerMobile").rules("add", { required: rule });
$("#CustomerWork").rules("add", { required: rule });
$("#CustomerHome").rules("add", { required: rule });
```

*UPDATE:*

Turns out my code was ok after all, but that `return` was on a line of its own, and that makes JS explode.

Would still like to know how to attach a single error message to the group, rather than have four errors show whe validation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @charlietfl's code works, here is a modified version of my original code, which works:

```
var eitherors = $("#CustomerEmail, #CustomerMobile, #CustomerWork, #CustomerHome");
var message  = "Please enter either a phone number or email address";

// define the required validation rule
// will return true when all inputs are blank
var requiredRule = function (el) {
  return eitherors
    .filter(function () { return $(this).val() !== "" })
    .length === 0;
};

// define the required validation error message
// returns the error message when 1) all inputs are
// blank, and 2) only for one of the fields (I chose the first one)
var requiredMessage = function (arg, el) {
  return (requiredRule() && eitherors.first().is(el))
    ? message
    : "";
};

// use same rule and message on all the "either-or" inputs
eitherors.each(function () {
  $(this).rules("add", {
    required: requiredRule,
    messages: { required: requiredMessage }
    });
  });
```

This is generic, so will work on any group of elements by only changing the jQuery array and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> validation to succeed if at least one field is populated

Your rule only succeeds if **ALL** fields have a value (since you are using the AND operator). If one is enough use the OR operator

```
var rule = function (el) {
  return
    $("#CustomerEmail").val() ||
    $("#CustomerMobile").val() ||
    $("#CustomerWork").val() ||
    $("#CustomerHome").val();
  };
```

Comment: A field is required if all the other fields are empty, i.e. logical and. But even if I change it to logical or, it doesn't work. Must be using the plugin incorrectly somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that first involves adding a new validation method for `Must_Have_One`. The method `name` is matching class added to each element in group, or you can use `rules` object to define the method.

HTML

```
<input name="name" class="must_have_one" />
```

JS

```
var $form_group=$('.must_have_one')

$.validator.addMethod("must_have_one", function() {
    var must_have_els=$form_group.filter(function(){
        return this.value !='';
    });

    if (must_have_els.length) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, 'Must have one of .....');

var myFormValidator = $("form").validate({
    groups: {
         must_have_one : "name email"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {       
        if (myFormValidator.groups[element.attr("name")]) {
            /* determine placement for message for group*/
            error.insertAfter($form_group.last());
        }
        else error.insertAfter(element);
    }
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UzjZM/1/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? Maybe because "must_have_els" is undefined?

Comment: i deleted something i shouldn't doing some refctoring for last update...try this http://jsfiddle.net/UzjZM/2/

Comment: This works excellently, but the real problem was in my syntax. See update.

Comment: @charlieftl how would I add the messages to my existing code above?

Comment: method I gave you includes message. You would have to write the message object and include all 4 fields doing it your way. See `messages` in docs